# How to create new entity and use it to find the entity in my test data? How to make my tokenize works?

Tags: python, nlp, entity

I would like to make a new entity: let's call it "medicine" and then train it using my corpora. From there, identify all the entities of "medicine". Somehow my code is not working, could anyone help me?

```
import nltk


test= input("Please enter your file name")
test1= input("Please enter your second file name")

with open(test, "r") as file:  
    new = file.read().splitlines()


with open(test1, "r") as file2:
    new1= file2.read().splitlines()


for s in new:
    for x in new1:
        sample = s.replace('value', x)

        sample1 = ''.join(str(v) for v in sample)

        print(sample1)


        sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(sample1)
        tokenized_sentences = [nltk.word_tokenize(sentence) for sentence in sentences]
        tagged_sentences = [nltk.pos_tag(sentence) for sentence in tokenized_sentences]
        chunked_sentences = nltk.ne_chunk_sents(tagged_sentences, binary=True)


        print(sentences)

def extract_entity_names(t):
    entity_names = []

    if hasattr(t, 'label') and t.label:
        if t.label() == 'NE':
            entity_names.append(' '.join([child[0] for child in t]))
        else:
            for child in t:
                entity_names.extend(extract_entity_names(child))

    return entity_names
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to create new entity and use it to find the entity in my test data?

Named entity recognizers are probabilistic, neural or linear models. In your code,

```
chunked_sentences = nltk.ne_chunk_sents(tagged_sentences, binary=True)
```

does this prediction. So if you want it to recognize new entity types you should first train a classifier on annotated data, containing the new entity type.

> Somehow my code is not working,

As I said before, you did not train the model of NLTK with your own data, so it is not working.

> How to make my tokenize works?

Tokenizer only extracts word tokens, which is done in your code by this line

```
tokenized_sentences = [nltk.word_tokenize(sentence) for sentence in sentences]
```

But, **tokenizer does not predict named entity directly.**

If you want to train a model to predict custom named entity like medicine using NLTK, then try [this tutorial.](https://nlpforhackers.io/training-ner-large-dataset/)

From my personal experience NLTK may not be suitable for this, look at [Spacy.](https://spacy.io/usage/training#section-ner)